# On Closing any Dockable pane in WPF, how to toggle the isChecked property of corresponding MenuItem?

Tags: c#, wpf

In Xaml i have

```
<Menu Height="30">
 <MenuItem Header="Menu">
   <MenuItem Header="pane1" isChecked="true" click="menu_click">
   <MenuItem Header="pane2" isChecked="true" click="menu_click">
   <MenuItem Header="pane3" isChecked="false" click="menu_click">
 </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

And from viewmodel class I am closing this pane from using delegate.

```
content.Closed += delegate(object s, EventArgs e)
{
//some code to close the pane when X icon is pressed of that pane
};
```

In Xaml.cs

```
public void menu_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
var i = (MenuItem)sender;
if(i.isChecked==false)
 i.isChecked = true;
else
 i.isChecked =false;
}
```

so on menu click i am able to toggle ischecked property of menu items, but when any dockable pane is closed within application, how can I toggle this isChecked property of corresponding menuitem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [event aggregator](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/event-aggregator.html) service toggle the isChecked property.

- Create an PaneClosedEvent.
- Subscribe to the event in xaml.cs
- Publish the event on pane closed.